# How to resolve "Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder"" while start hbase

Tags: hbase

I try to start my hbase cluster by command `start-hbase.sh`. I got follow errors:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/michael/opt/modules/hbase/hbase-2.4.11/lib/client-facing-thirdparty/slf4j-reload4j-1.7.33.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/michael/opt/modules/hadoop/hadoop-3.3.2/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.30.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Reload4jLoggerFactory]
```

Then I check by `jps`, there is no any process about hbase. Then I delete the file `/home/michael/opt/modules/hbase/hbase-2.4.11/lib/client-facing-thirdparty/slf4j-reload4j-1.7.33.jar` and run `start-hbase.sh` again. This time I got error

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
```

I'm using hbase2.4.11 and hadoop3.3.2. How can I resolve this error? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

OK, it's just an warning, I just skip it!